# Extracting identifiable data by websites from one VM to another

Tags: google-chrome, virtual-machine, user-profiles, azure, cloud

Apologies I'm not a techy..... I currently use Windows 10 virtual machines on VMWare Workstation for a few projects and wanted to know if there is a way to export all the identifiable data that a website could access and copy it to a completely new virtual machine. I'm thinking cookies, browser history, things like that.

I have outgrown the capabilities of running simultaneous virtual machines on my local hardware so am considering using cloud based computing such as Azure. I wish for websites to see all my previous history (if they wish to do so) and not to see me as a new user or as a user that has wiped all of their traceable data. I used to use applications like CCleaner or to just use a 'new' W10 VM but that has caused issues for me in the past.

My humble appreciation for anyone who can lend the time and expertise to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Google Chrome article
[Sync your account settings](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/2914794?hl=en):

> You can save and sync things like your history, bookmarks, and passwords to your Google Account.

Cookies are not listed as synced. If they are not,
you may physically copy them by copying the file:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks for your input. Is there anything else that a website could you to create a profile of me as a user that I may need to transfer?

Comment: That's it, as far as I know. Feel free to ask if something is missing.